# Procfile Error Deploying Rails API with Dokku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku, entry-point, procfile, docker-entrypoint

I am currently trying to deploy my Rails API on Dokku, I keep running into this error where it says "Proc entrypoint [procname] does not exist. Please check your Procfile". I'm not sure what the issue is and how to set up an entrypoint, I've tried searching all over and have not been able to find an example of this being implemented.

Here is the full log of when I try to push to dokku master:

```
Counting objects: 232, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (212/212), done.
Writing objects: 100% (232/232), 35.48 KiB | 2.22 MiB/s, done.
Total 232 (delta 83), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (83/83), done.
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building iris-lune-api from herokuish...
-----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
-----> Fetching custom buildpack
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.4
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
       Using rake 12.3.3
       Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
       Using i18n 1.6.0
       Using minitest 5.11.3
       Using thread_safe 0.3.6
       Using tzinfo 1.2.5
       Using activesupport 5.2.3
       Using builder 3.2.3
       Using erubi 1.8.0
       Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
       Using nokogiri 1.10.4
       Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Using crass 1.0.4
       Using loofah 2.2.3
       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.2.0
       Using actionview 5.2.3
       Using rack 2.0.7
       Using rack-test 1.1.0
       Using actionpack 5.2.3
       Using nio4r 2.5.1
       Using websocket-extensions 0.1.4
       Using websocket-driver 0.7.1
       Using actioncable 5.2.3
       Using globalid 0.4.2
       Using activejob 5.2.3
       Using mini_mime 1.0.2
       Using mail 2.7.1
       Using actionmailer 5.2.3
       Using activemodel 5.2.3
       Using case_transform 0.2
       Using jsonapi-renderer 0.2.2
       Using active_model_serializers 0.10.10
       Using arel 9.0.0
       Using activerecord 5.2.3
       Using mimemagic 0.3.3
       Using marcel 0.3.3
       Using activestorage 5.2.3
       Using msgpack 1.3.1
       Using bootsnap 1.4.5
       Using bundler 1.17.2
       Using method_source 0.9.2
       Using pg 1.1.4
       Using puma 3.12.1
       Using rack-cors 1.0.3
       Using thor 0.20.3
       Using railties 5.2.3
       Using sprockets 3.7.2
       Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Using rails 5.2.3
       Using stripe 5.1.1 from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby (at master@1f80da4)
       Bundle complete! 12 Gemfile dependencies, 50 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
       Removing bundler (1.15.2)
       Bundle completed (0.44s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Detecting rails configuration

       ###### WARNING:

       You set your `config.active_storage.service` to :local in production.
       If you are uploading files to this app, they will not persist after the app
       is restarted, on one-off dynos, or if the app has multiple dynos.
       Heroku applications have an ephemeral file system. To
       persist uploaded files, please use a service such as S3 and update your Rails
       configuration.

       For more information can be found in this article:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku


       ###### WARNING:

       We detected that some binary dependencies required to
       use all the preview features of Active Storage are not
       present on this system.

       For more information please see:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku


       ###### WARNING:

       No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
       We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server


-----> Discovering process types
       Default types for  -> rake, console, web
-----> Releasing iris-lune-api (dokku/iris-lune-api:latest)...
-----> Deploying iris-lune-api (dokku/iris-lune-api:latest)...
-----> App Procfile file found (/home/dokku/iris-lune-api/DOKKU_PROCFILE)
       DOKKU_SCALE declares scale -> web=1 [procname]=1
-----> Attempting pre-flight checks
       For more efficient zero downtime deployments, create a file CHECKS.
       See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/zero-downtime-deploys/ for examples
       CHECKS file not found in container: Running simple container check...
-----> Waiting for 10 seconds ...
-----> Default container check successful!
-----> Attempting pre-flight checks
       Non web container detected: Running default container check...
-----> Waiting for 10 seconds ...
b442e9261dad2aa7c0590575295cf227c42fee5337729907e9382484effd8ab7
remote: App container failed to start!!
=====> iris-lune-api [procname] container output:
       Proc entrypoint [procname] does not exist. Please check your Procfile
       Proc entrypoint [procname] does not exist. Please check your Procfile
       Proc entrypoint [procname] does not exist. Please check your Procfile
       Proc entrypoint [procname] does not exist. Please check your Procfile
       Proc entrypoint [procname] does not exist. Please check your Procfile
       Proc entrypoint [procname] does not exist. Please check your Procfile
       Proc entrypoint [procname] does not exist. Please check your Procfile
=====> end iris-lune-api [procname] container output
To 67.205.164.245:iris-lune-api
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring this out, I had to create a file in the root directory called "DOKKU_SCALE" and add this text to the file:

```
web=1
worker=1
```